# APPX0502 Build fail in tfs but work in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, build, tfs-2015

I had many problems, but this is something that can not be resolved when the TFS makes a compilation fails but works well when the compilation is done from the Visual Studio 2015.
I have installed: TFS 2015.

Error:

> (1736,5): Error APPX0502: File 'C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Windows
>   Kits\10\Include\WinRT\AppxManifestSchema2010_v2.xsd' not found.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this on my Dev Machine by copying 2 files from the Win8.1 Kit to the Win10 kit folders

Source:

- "C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\AppxManifestSchema2010_v2.xsd"
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
  Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\AppxManifestSchema2013.xsd"

Target:

- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
  Kits\10\Include\winrt\AppxManifestSchema2010_v2.xsd"
- "C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\winrt\AppxManifestSchema2013.xsd"

No idea how legit this is, or why it it needed for building from MSBuild when you can build fine in VS.